# custom chapter numbering with decimals

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I would like to start a `report` with the `Chapter 3.6` (and consecutive) until `3.9`. I have been looking for these types of commands, but they are not working as I want.

Please help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your chapters should start with 3.6.. What is 3.6 then? A section?

Comment: Oh God! Silly me! Yes, I meant, Section 3.6!

Answer (score 3):

```
\renewcomand\thechapter{3.\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{5}
```

in the preamble should make the first `\chapter` 3.6

Comment: Your answer has a spelling mistake and missing brackets. It should be `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{3.\arabic{chapter}}`

Answer (score 2):

Principally it's possible to set the counters of `chapter and`section` accordingly, but it will look a little bit strange.

Since the `section` counter is reset each time the `chapter` counter is increased, the setting of `section` counter must be done **after** `\chapter` is called.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My real first chapter}
\setcounter{section}{5}

\section{A section}

\blindtext[5]

\section{A} % Will be 3.7
\section{B} % 3.8
\section{c} % 3.9

\chapter{Second chapter}  % Sections are set to 1, chapter is 4 now
\section{Start over with 1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Class with chapters

If the class contains chapters and the "3" in "3.6" means the chapter number:

```
\documentclass{report}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Forth section}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for class report]

## Class without chapters

If the class does not contain chapters such as `article`, then the appearance of the section counter can be prefixed with `3.`. The longer section number also requires more place in the table of contents, see the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd\thesection{3.}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\thesection failed}%
}
\setcounter{section}{5}

% Extra place is needed for the section number in the table of contents
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@section{1.5em}{2.3em}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\l@section failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Forth section}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for class article]